# flexbox max-width and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I use a `flexbox` like the below with `max-width`. This code works fine for Google Chrome and gives the result:

[image]

But it bugs in Internet Explorer erasing the start and displaying it in a single line:

[image]

I don't know what's wrong with `max-width` and how can I fix this... Some help pls!

```css
.d1 {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  A Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test B
</div>
```

Comment: You're not including prefixed flexbox properties for best browser support so depending on what version of IE you're talking about, Flexbox may be completely unsupported or you may be missing one of the necessary prefixed properties. See [Backwards Compatibility of Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Backwards_Compatibility_of_Flexbox). Also check out [Flexy Boxes](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes) and turn on "Generate legacy flexbox styles".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex-flow: row wrap;` with `align-items: center` or you use `flex-flow: column wrap;` with `justify-content: center;` your call.

check my code its working as you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .d1 {
    color: #fff;
      background: blue;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      max-width: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="d1">
    A Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test B
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```